# Is Spring affected by the underlying database?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

I am trying to write a guide on how to get started with Spring-boot+Tomcat+React.js

This is an educational piece for a project with a lot of different developers. We know that we will use PostGreSQL, but I want the guide to be to the point as much as possible.

Is the Spring code at all affected by the underlying database choice?

From: https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/01/react-js-and-spring-data-rest-part-1-basic-features

> Spring Boot makes it extremely convenient for programmers to quickly develop Spring applications using an in-memory database, such as H2, HSQLDB, and Derby. These databases are lightweight, easy to use, and emulates other RDBMS with the help of JPA and Hibernate. Obviously, they don’t provide persistent storage; but they a fast way to test persistent functions of your Spring Boot application without going through the hassles of installing a database server. They are great to use during development when you need to populate your database once your application starts, test your persistent entity mappings, and remove any data when your application ends. To use the embedded databases, you don’t need any special configuration, not even any connection URL. If you are using Maven, you only specify the dependency of the database to use in the POM file. Spring Boot automatically sets up the in-memory database for your use when it finds the database on your classpath.
>
> In-memory databases are useful in the early development stages in local environments, but they have lot’s of restrictions. As the development progresses, you would most probably require an RDBMS to develop and test your application before deploying it to use a production database server, such as Oracle, MySQL, or PostgreSQL.

Would for instance the class (also from: https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/01/react-js-and-spring-data-rest-part-1-basic-features)

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Employee {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String description;

    private Employee() {}

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String description) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

have to be modified in anyway when using PostGreSQL as opposed to an in-memory database?

Cheers and kind regards,
Filip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You configure a database in the hibernate configuration. For plain Hibernate it is `hibernate.properties` or `hibernate.cfg.xml`. It doesn't affect persistent classes.

Comment: With spring boot the configuration can go in `application.yml`; no need for hibernate specific configuration files, and easier to override when including a project as dependency.